# How to preload EJB instances on JBOss

Tags: jboss

Is there a way to pre-load EJB instances (stateless) in JBoss 4.2.0?  I know there isn't any configuration option for this, but could I write my own MBean or something to do this?

-Dave

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not neccessary according to this [article](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/do_we_need_stateless_session)

in `$JBOSS_HOME/server/default/conf/standardjboss.xml`
you find

```
<container-pool-conf>
        <MaximumSize>100</MaximumSize>
</container-pool-conf>
```

for both container-confgiurations `Clustered Stateless SessionBean` and

```
Standard Stateless SessionBean
```

Looking in the DTD shows MinimumSize as an optional element in container configuration for experimenting you could set the MinimumSize and check whether some server code cars about.

```
<!--
  The container-pool-conf element holds configuration data for the
  instance pool.
  jboss does not read directly the subtree for this element: instead,
  it is passed to the instance pool instance (if it implements
  org.jboss.metadata.XmlLoadable) for it to load its parameters.

  The default instance pools, EntityInstancePool and
  StatelessSessionInstancePool, both accept the following configuration.

  Used in: container-configuration
-->
<!ELEMENT container-pool-conf ((MinimumSize?, MaximumSize?,
   strictMaximumSize?, strictTimeout?) | Synchronized)>
```

Comment: It looks like that won't work.

http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/admindevel326/html/ch5.chapter.html

"All current JBoss InstancePool implementations derive from the org.jboss.ejb.plugins.AbstractInstancePool class and it provides support for the MinimumSize, MaximumSize, strictMaximumSize and strictTimeout container-pool-conf child elements. The MinimumSize element gives the minimum number of instances to keep in the pool, although JBoss does not currently seed an InstancePool to the MinimumSize value."